# Cannot change theme in magento2 admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme

I cannot change theme in `content -> configuration -> Default Store View`,  I am getting following error:

[image]

It always stays **--No Theme--**, tried changing to **Blank Theme** and my **custom theme**.

I am using **xampp** and **C:/xampp/htdocs/magento2new** is correct. Not sure what magento is trying to find?

Comment: either files not in place or read permission not there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818146/compilation-from-source-cannot-read-contents-from-file-on-static-content-deplo http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156909/error-cannot-read-contents-from-file-when-changing-themes-from-admin-panel  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100350/cannot-read-contents-from-file-app-design-adminhtml-magento-backend-etc-module-x

Answer (score 1):

Please copy the email folder from

```
  \vendor\magento\module-email\view\frontend\email
```

to

```
  \vendor\magento\module-email\view\adminhtml\email\. IT's works.
```

Please check also this issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5666#issuecomment-233236951